# Modx GetImageList: Retrieve Every Other MIGX Entry

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, migx

I am trying to have GetImageList retrieve every other/second entry in the MIGX tv. This way I can have two calls and split them up between two bootstrap columns. It just looks better that way. What parameters can I include in the snippet to do so?

```
[[getImageList?
    &tvname=`Success Stories`
    &tpl=`successtpl`
]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use two getImageList calls, one in each column, each with a different conditional based on [[+_alt]]:

```
[[+_alt:is=`1`:then=`
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 cl-stacked-margin-bottom">
            <div id="cl-tesimonial">
                <div class="testimonial-content"><i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    [[+client_testimony]]                   
                    <h2 class="cl-client-name">[[+client_name]]</h2>
                    <div class="cl-author image-testimonial"> <img src="[[+client_img:notempty=`[[+client_img]]`:else=`[[++assets_url]]img/client_images/testimonial.jpg" alt="[[+client_name]]">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
`:else=``]]
```

and:

```
[[+_alt:is=`1`:then=``:else=`
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 cl-stacked-margin-bottom">
            <div id="cl-tesimonial">
                <div class="testimonial-content"><i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    [[+client_testimony]]                   
                    <h2 class="cl-client-name">[[+client_name]]</h2>
                    <div class="cl-author image-testimonial"> <img src="[[+client_img:notempty=`[[+client_img]]`:else=`[[++assets_url]]img/client_images/testimonial.jpg" alt="[[+client_name]]">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
`]]
```